# Detect a new file, and send it with mpack

Tags: linux, email, debian, attachment

I have a very specific question. I am using Debian.
I have an FTP folder where an app will upload a pdf-file, and the file will be stored in ftpfolder/EMAIL_ADDRESS, and the name of the file will be CURRENT_DATE_AND_TIME.

What I want to do is whenever a new file is uploaded, in either of the EMAIL_ADDRESS folders, to send the file with mpack. As you might have guessed I want the file sent to the name of the folder, with the file attached.

So to break it down I need to:

- Detect whenever a new file is uploaded
- Extract the address from the foldername
- Extract the filename, and attach it with mpack
- Send it

I am stumped on how to approach this problem, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a cron that would launch a script doing all the stuff you need and then archive the files found in another folder?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ftpfolder; 
for email in *; do 
    mpack -s "New PDF file uploaded" $email/* $email; 
    mv $email /archivefolder; 
done
```

Pros:

- simplicity

Cons:

- you have to have write permissions to move files
- messing up with the original files

Note that the above script assumes only one file appears in the folder between the cron executions. If you cannot assure that (i.e. expect more than one file within a minute) you might have to loop over the folder contents.